# RStudio: Error on testing documentation with?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using latest RStudio 0.99.879. I'm creating a new project as R Package.

After running (as mentioned on http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html)

```
devtools::document()
?.
```

I get an error

```
/path/to/my/package/man: Sections \title, and \name must exist and be unique in Rd files
```

What's the reason and how can I avoid it?

**Edit:** I've deleted manually the file man/hello.Rd so roxygen2 can generate it.

Comment: Doesn't the error message give you a clue? Do you have Rd files without \title or \name sections or that aren't unique? Can't tell without your code...

Comment: @Spacedman No, unfortunately not. There is just one file (so there is uniqueness) and \title and \name aren't empty.

Comment: Are you literally typing "?." because you've defined "." in your package?

Comment: @Spacedman Ah, I thought "?." has some magic behaviour so the man-page for the function I'm currently editing is opened. "?hello" work's as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadley told me "." is the end of the sentence. So there's no magic.